# Can an iterative method converge for some initial approximation?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Studying iterative methods for solving(or approximating) linear equation systems, I came accross the following theorem$^1$:

> Let the following be an iterative method:
>   $$x^{(0)},\qquad   known\\
> x^{(k+1)}=Bx^{(k)}+g,\quad k=1,2,...$$
>
> where B is the iteration matrix and g is a vector.
>
> The iterative method converges, for any chosen initial approximation $x^{(0)}$, if and only if $\rho(B)\lt 1$, where $\rho(B) = max_{i=1,...,n} \left\{|\lambda_i| : \lambda_i \text{ is an eigenvalue of B}\right\}$

So, basically, the method converges, for any chosen initial approximation, *iff* the maximum absolute value of B's eigenvalues is less than 1.

**My question**

I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the theorem:

1. For any chosen $x^{(0)}$: (the method converges $\Leftrightarrow \rho(B) \lt 1$)
2. (The method converges for any chosen $x^{(0)}) \Leftrightarrow \rho(B) \lt 1$

So, if $\rho(B) \ge 1$, does the method always diverge(interpretation 1), or can it converge for some (but not all) initial approximation (interpretation 2)?

---

$^1$(translated by me, if some terms are a bit off please let me know)

Comment: 2. Because you if some $\lambda < 1$ ($\rho(B)>1$ )and $g$ is in span of small $\lambda$ you can find an initial $x_0$ such that the method still  converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method converges for any $x^{(0)}$ if and only if $\rho(B)<1$.

Inverting the equivalence gives (recall how the quantifiers are negated):

> There is an $x^{(0)}$ such that the method does not converge (diverges or stagnate) if and only if $\rho(B)\geq 1$.

Note that the inversion does not say anything about the existence of $x^{(0)}$ for which the method converges. Two scenarios are possible:

- You might find an initial guess such that the method converges for some $x^{(0)}$. Note that for the error $e^{(k)}=x-x^{(k)}$, one has $e^{(k)}=Be^{(k-1)}=B^ke^{(0)}$, where $e^{(0)}$ is the error associated with the initial approximation $x^{(0)}$. The method hence converges if $e^{(0)}\in\mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is some invariant subspace  of $B$ corresponding to the eigenvalues of $B$ with the magnitudes strictly smaller than one.
- If all eigenvalues of $B$ are in magnitude larger or equal to one, then the method does not converge for any initial guess (except the trivial case where $x^{(0)}=x$, that is, $e^{(0)}=0$).

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification, as well as the extra bit of information (it can converge only if there's some eigenvalue < 1). I was having trouble inverting the equivalence because I wasn't quite sure what the equivalence was in the first place, but your first statement took care of that. Again, thank you.